# Wrong result of mysql query - where is the mistake?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have a problem with my mysql query. The result of the query shows statistics of football team. The problem: If a player scored 2 goals at one game, then count 2 times "starter" instead of 1 times "starter". If a player scored 3 goals at one game, then my query count 3 "starter" instead of 1 "starter".

Please help where is the problem, I have no idea:
Here is the Mysql query:

```
'SELECT '.TBL_PERSONS.'.id AS id_person, '.TBL_PERSONS.'.firstname AS firstname, '.TBL_PERSONS.'.lastname AS lastname,
count(case when '.TBL_LINEUP.'.type = 2 then 1 else NULL end) AS starter,
sum(case when '.TBL_LINEUP.'.type = 3 then 1 else 0 end) AS bench,
sum(case when GOALS.id_person = '.TBL_LINEUP.'.id_person then 1 else 0 end) AS goal,
sum(case when ASSIST.assist_id = '.TBL_LINEUP.'.id_person then 1 else 0 end) AS assist
FROM '.TBL_LINEUP.'

JOIN '.TBL_MATCHS.' ON '.TBL_LINEUP.'.id_match = '.TBL_MATCHS.'.id AND 
'.TBL_MATCHS.'.id_season = "2" AND '.TBL_MATCHS.'.id_compet = "2" AND '.TBL_MATCHS.'.validation = "1"

JOIN '.TBL_PERSONS.' ON '.TBL_LINEUP.'.id_person = '.TBL_PERSONS.'.id

LEFT JOIN '.TBL_GOALS.' AS GOALS  ON '.TBL_LINEUP.'.id_person = GOALS.id_person AND '.TBL_MATCHS.'.id = GOALS.id_match AND GOALS.goal_csc = 0

LEFT JOIN '.TBL_GOALS.' AS ASSIST ON 
'.TBL_LINEUP.'.id_person = ASSIST.assist_id AND '.TBL_LINEUP.'.id_match = ASSIST.id_match

WHERE '.TBL_LINEUP.'.id_club = 36
GROUP BY id_person';
```

If I remove the left join of goals

```
LEFT JOIN '.TBL_GOALS.' AS GOALS  ON '.TBL_LINEUP.'.id_person = GOALS.id_person AND '.TBL_MATCHS.'.id = GOALS.id_match AND GOALS.goal_csc = 0
```

then the result of query looks good.

Database structure:

**tbl_lineup**: id, id_match, id_club, id_person, type

**tbl_persons:** id, lastname, firstname

**tbl_matchs:** id_candidate_dom, id_candidate_ext, id_season, id_compet

**tbl_goals:** id, id_match, id_person, id_club, goal_min, goal_csc (0 normal goal, 1 own goal), goal_pen (0 not, 1 penalty goal), assist_id (player id of the goal assist)

Please help me because I have no idea what is the problem with my query. Many thanks.

Comment: Your `count()` to starters should probably be a `sum(case when..)` as the others as well

Comment: Hi, earlier I have try with sum, but the result is the same.

Comment: Sample data would help.

Comment: *Here is the Mysql query:* Please replace the code with the value after all concatenations and substitutions.

Comment: *If a player scored 2 goals at one game, then count 2 times "starter" instead of 1 times "starter".* You must count distinct games amount where `type = 2`. I.e. something like `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tbl_lineup.type = 2 THEN tbl_matchs.id END)`.

Comment: Many thanks Akina, your solution is good!

Comment: @Akina It's best not to put answers into comments, because they can't be edited, voted on, etc, and can't be "accepted" to mark the question as resolved. Comments should be used to refine the question to get it into a good enough state to answer; if you think it's already good enough, just post an Answer.

Comment: @Liverpool Please can you [edit] your question to include a [mcve] - a set of table definitions and sample data, a complete SQL query without any placeholders, and the current and desired output. That helps avoid ambiguity in the requirements, and means we can test possible solutions before posting them.

Comment: @IMSoP I must be sure that the provided method solves the problem. In current state I cannot be sure - so I use comment form (and ask to provide final SQL code) which explains the principle way.

Comment: @Akina But now you've given the OP what they needed, so there's no incentive for them to write a better question, now or in the future. They get what they want, but the site is left with half a question and half an answer. I hope I'm wrong in this case, but the general principle stands: answers in comments are bad for the site as a whole.

Comment: @IMSoP Well, I'll do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your query uses the next expression:

```
count(case when '.TBL_LINEUP.'.type = 2 then 1 else NULL end) AS starter
```

This expression counts the goals and does not distinguish in what games they were scored.

You need to count not the goals itself, but the games in which these goals were scored. Each goal must be replaced with unique game identifier, and distinct identifiers amount must be counted.

So the code may look like

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tbl_lineup.type = 2 THEN tbl_matchs.id END) AS starter
```

If 2 goals were scored in different games then 2 different `id`s will be counted. But if 2 goals were scored in the same game then 2 equal `id`s will be produced, and DISTINCT will count them only once.

The rows with `type != 2` will produce NULL because CASE have no ELSE section, and hence they will be ignored by COUNT(). If you want to obtain zero instead NULL for players (?) who have no scored goals then wrap the expression with COALESCE(), i.e.

```
COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tbl_lineup.type = 2 THEN tbl_matchs.id END), 0) AS starter
```